# link_to edit goes to login instead of modal partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want my edit button to display the edit modal partial.

I am using has_secure_password for users to login to an admin page where they see their products in a model backed bootstrap table with an edit and delete button on each row. The button code is:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_product_path(product), remote: true, class: 
    "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Delete", product_delete_path(product), remote: true, 
    class: "orange btn btn-primary btn-sm" %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

My edit_product_path is:

```
edit_product GET    /products/:id/edit(.:format)           products#edit
```

Outside of this table I have this line for the modal

```
<div id="product-modal" class="modal fade"></div>
```

When I click the edit button nothing happens, but in the terminal I see

```
Started GET "/products/69/edit" for 108.90...
Processing by ProductsController#edit as JS
Parameters: {"id"=>"69"}
Redirected to https://this-xxxxx-work-xxxxx.c9.io/login

Started GET "/login"
Processing by SessionsController#new as JS
Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 131ms (Views: 129.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

My Products controller edit action is basic:

```
def edit
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

I use the pry gem, and when I put binding.pry in the edit controller it gets skipped, so it seems like its not really hitting the edit controller.

This is in my edit.js.erb file

```
$("#product-modal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'product') %>");
$("#product-modal").modal("show")
```

Comment: Do you have some type of authorization method that runs before each route in your controller? That is generally what redirects to login

Comment: Hmm, good question.. I don't think so.. but I have another route that I left in for testing that bypasses the login, those modals work fine.. but I just looked and when clicked they have an authenticity token being passed.. That has got to be the problem..

Comment: You may have before filter for user authentication that's why it goes to login page

Comment: Definitely a `before_filter`/`before_action`. Look for it in your ProductsController and all of it ancestors.

Comment: I figured it out.. it ended up being another place where the session was being stored.. It was created by a gem that I was using, and obliviously I didn't understand.. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!